# How to hide iOS 6 UIButton "gradient"?

Tags: ios6, uibutton

When I place a UIButton on view that doesn't contain any white, a strange "gradient" is shown on the bottom of the button. This doesn't happen in iOS 5, nor does it happen when the background of the view beneath contains some white.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: You see, on the bottom there's a sort of extra line, which I find quite ugly...]

How do I remove/hide this effect?

Comment: Please add a screenshot.

Comment: Can you see the ugly "3D effect" line on the bottom?

Comment: I know exactly what you mean and I agree that it's ugly and annoying.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIButton Rounded Rect unwanted 3D effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726335/uibutton-rounded-rect-unwanted-3d-effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the only way around this is to make Custom button. It's part of the Rounded Rect button and you can't get rid of it.

There's some interesting discussion of the problem here:

[Button background and gradient change since iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564738/button-background-and-gradient-change-since-ios6?rq=1)